# redirect missing pages - why isn't this working?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this in my .htaccess file. I think it should redirect http://bashof.org/Hall_of_Fame_1980.html - to -> http://bashof.org/category/inductees/1980/

Anyone know why it isn't working?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Hall_of_Fame_1980\.html category/inductees/1980/ [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Move this redirect rule below `RewriteEngine` line.

Comment: I moved the line under the first     RewriteEngine On     line, and it still doesn't work.